# Convert String with multiple numbers to Integers in java

Tags: java

```
package averagewithmethods;

/**
*
* @author ryost
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AverageWithMethods {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    String inputString = inputNumberString();
    double average = averageNumbers(inputString);
    System.out.print(average);
}
/**
 * A method to get the number string from the user
 * @return String inputString
 */
public static String inputNumberString() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString;
    System.out.print("Enter between 5 and 10 numbers, separated by spaces, 
to be averaged: ");
    inputString = in.nextLine();
    return inputString;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5 10"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at averagewithmethods.AverageWithMethods.averageNumbers(AverageWithMethods.java:47)
    at averagewithmethods.AverageWithMethods.main(AverageWithMethods.java:20)
C:\Users\ryost\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I'm trying to have a string inputted by the user and then get an average returned. The big problem I'm having is in converting each individual integer within a string into separate integers to be able to calculate the average.

Example- Input:5 10 20 10 5
Output: Average is 10

```
 public static double averageNumbers(String inputString) {
    double average;
    int numSpaces;
    int a = 0;

    inputString = inputString.trim();
    numSpaces = inputString.length() - inputString.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
    for (int i = 0; i < (numSpaces + 1); i++) {
        a = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(i));
    }
    average = a / (numSpaces + 1);
    return average;
}
```

Comment: what number do you think the String `5 10` should be?

Comment: **and** as the error is happening in `averageNumbers` do you not think it would be a good idea to share this code?

Comment: So, the string 5 10 20 10 5 should end up as 5 separate integers: 5, 10, 20, 10, 5 which are then averaged out to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use split

```
int sum = 0;

String inputString = "5 10 20 10 5";
String []arr = inputString.split(" ");

for (String str : arr) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(str);   //+= here
}

System.out.println("Average is " + (double) sum / arr.length);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, would it be possible to accomplish this without using an array?

Comment: yeah you could loop looking for indexOf `<space>`, then grabbing a `substring`